# how to select the nested list?

Tags: html, css

```
    <div id="drop">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>           
            </ul>

            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>           
            </ul>

            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>           
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How to select nested listhere to apply specific operations on them i want to display the nested list in blocks and parent list as inline?

EDIT
Sorry i made a mistake i donot want to use classes for list items and wanna do with only #drop

Comment: you select the nested list by using `.nested`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select main list: `#drop > ul`

To select child list:  `#drop > ul > ul`

Note that you cannot have duplicate ids on the same page.

I suggest you nest the child `ul` inside the parent `li` this way. This makes it easier to style the drop down. The selector will be `#drop > ul > li > ul` in this case.

```css
#drop a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#drop li:hover > a {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#drop > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
#drop > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#drop > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
#drop > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#drop > ul > li > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>           
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>          
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>         
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't the inline property applied on li elements? am i wong?

Comment: can we do like this  in general  instead of using this property on li ,     ul{  dispaly:inline;}    to display the list items inline?

Comment: There, I made an example for you.

Comment: can you give a link where i can study these selectors in easy way?